# Style not applied when using htaccess

Tags: php, css, .htaccess, redirect

I want to show the url based on country selected, so i have used htaccess to redirect url based on the country selected. for example, i want the url to be like this:  `www.example.com/us/index.html`

i have my files like the following,

```
public_html/includes/style.css  
public_html/index.php
```

in index.php i've linked the style sheet like "`../includes/style.css`"

when i tried `www.example.com` the style applied correctly. once the user selected the country in index.php, url will be redirected as `www.example.com/us/index.html`. But for this redirected page the style was not applied correctly.

i've following condition in .htaccess to redirect the page,

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^\.]+)\.html$ index.php?cnt=$1 [L]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. This is the code which i used to solve the issue:

```
$base = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  
$base=parse_url($base);  
$parts=explode("/",$base['path']);  
$path=$parts[1];  
$home="/".$path;  

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='$home/includes/style.css'/>
```

However it worked for me only when i run this in localhost Because i put my files under `home/localhost/example/`
 But when i put it on server, again i faced the style problem. so i simply changed the home variable like this :

```
$home="";
```

so now the path becomes,

```
/includes/style.css
```

instead of

```
//includes/style.css
```

Answer (score 2):

When visiting www.example.com/us/index.html, the style.css computed url is www.example.com/us/includes/style.css which obviously doesn't exists.

So, depending of what your intend is, either

- use a absolute link for the style sheet like "/includes/style.css"
- create a htaccess rewrite rule to fix the url
- create 1 style sheet per country

Answer (score 1):

If you're including your CSS files with relative paths your CSS will return a 404 when your URL moves beyond the initial home directory (or seems to move out, when using .htaccess)

The solution to this is to use an absolute path when including your css

instead of `../includes/style.css`

Use `<?php echo $webroot; ?>/includes/style.css`

`$webroot` here being the full path to the webroot of your project

Comment: Thanks. I've used the same, in header i've a variable $home which holds the path like $home="../". while linking style sheet i used like href="<?php echo "$home.includes/style.css"; ?>" . is it correct?

Comment: nope. $home is still be a relative path. you need to get the base URL of your domain. If you're using a virtual host you can simply use /includes/style.css but if you're using something like http://localhost/project1 then you have to figure out what your webroot is in your index.php. what kind of setup do you have?

Comment: you're right. For testing purpose i put my files under "localhost/projects/sample/". the sample folder contains the directories like includes/style.css and files like index.php,.htaccess. is there any specific function to get the baseurl in php?

Comment: Well, if your index.php file is inside `/sample` and all the requests come to that file AND your css files are in `/sample/includes/` then you could use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the current directory and then append `/includes` to it. Much easier if you're using a framework. PHP link : http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Answer (score 1):

it should be `/includes/style.css`, not ../includes/style.css, that's all.
always use absolute path.